# Git+Bash / GitBash: Add files matching both first-letter-uppercase or all-lowercase filenames of certain pattern along with respective plurals

Tags: regex, bash, git, git-bash, git-add

I have some Laravel/Livewire files matching filename patterns like seen in below:

```
app/Livewire/String1Table.php
app/Livewire/String1s.php
app/Livewire/EditString1.php

app/Models/String2Table.php
app/Models/SubDir/SomeString2.php

resources/views/livewire/string1-table.blade.php
resources/views/livewire/string1s.blade.php
resources/views/livewire/edit-string1.blade.php
```

Now I want to `git add` only those files that contain `String1` or `string1` (apparently disregarding the case) and only those that are within the [L|l]ivewire folder (disregarding the case here too).

I know that `git add` supports the asterisk and some of regex, but does it support all the bash related pattern matches ? Any ideas on how can I achieve what I want? Hope the requirement is clear.

From the first 2 informative comments, I am wondering if this would be correct: `git add *[Ll]ivewire/*String1[?s]` ? I am not so well-versed with regex that much, that's why I wanna know if anyone can come up with a way or partial way. I don't wanna end up adding files incorrectly.

Comment: The command line arguments to `git add` will be expanded by Bash, so its patterns should work for you.

Comment: You can find the complete description of git's pathspec syntax [in the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec). Git itself only support fairly simple glob patterns. You can of course always use a different tool (e.g. shell globs, `find`, `fzf`, etc) to find the files and run `git add` on them.

Comment: Ok those are good points, though when I try to think on way, I keep getting into thought rabbit-hole, would this be correct: `git add *[Ll]ivewire/*String1[?s]` ? I am not so well-versed with regex that much, that's why I wanna know if anyone can come up with a way or partial way. I don't wanna end up adding incorrectly.

Comment: @VickyDev Unless you're using a special shell that understands regexs, no. Bash has its own glob pattern syntax which is similiar-ish but unrelated to regexs. See for example https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html. You can trivially check whether a glob pattern works in bash by running `echo <pattern>` and seeing if the files you expect are listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` to locate the desired files:

```bash
$ find . -path '*/[Ll]ivewire/*' -name '*[Ss]tring1*'
./app/Livewire/String1s.php
./app/Livewire/EditString1.php
./app/Livewire/String1Table.php
./resources/views/livewire/string1-table.blade.php
./resources/views/livewire/edit-string1.blade.php
./resources/views/livewire/string1s.blade.php
```

Once you have a `find` command that matches the desired files, you can run `git add` on each file by passing an `-exec` option:

```bash
$ find . -path '*/[Ll]ivewire/*' -name '*[Ss]tring1*' -exec git add '{}' +
$ git status -s
A  app/Livewire/EditString1.php
A  app/Livewire/String1Table.php
A  app/Livewire/String1s.php
A  resources/views/livewire/edit-string1.blade.php
A  resources/views/livewire/string1-table.blade.php
A  resources/views/livewire/string1s.blade.php
?? app/Models/
```

Comment: P.S.: strictly speaking you can merge the `-path` and `-name` options into a single `-path` option, but I opted to include both to be a bit more illustrative of what `find` can do.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running Bash 4.3 or later then this should work:

```
shopt -s dotglob globstar
git add **/[Ll]ivewire/*[Ss]tring1*.php
```

- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the command:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` processes such files by default.
  - `globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.  This option was introduced with Bash 4.0 (released in 2009) but it is dangerous to use in versions before 4.3 (released in 2014) because it follows symlinks.  See the [globstar](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globstar_.28since_bash_4.0-alpha.29) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).